# Restify Multiple Domain SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, restify

How do I use multiple ssl certificates for multiple domains with Restify ?

With `https` package , you can use multiples ssl certificates through the option
`SNICallback`.
But this option are not present on Restify.

Comment: did you get any answers on this?